# How do initialize a postgresql db in terraform's helm provider?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-helm

I am unsuccessful so far in passing an `initdbScript` into a helm provider for terraform to create the database. Has anybody tried this?

This is my attempt for the .tf file:

```
resource "helm_release" "database" {
  name  = "database"
  chart = "stable/postgresql"

  set {
    name  = "postgresqlUsername"
    value = "user"
  }

  set {
    name  = "postgresqlPassword"
    value = "xxx"
  }

  set {
    name  = "initdbScripts"
    value = "init.sql: |${file("../backend/init.sql")}"
  }
}
```

It looks like as `helm` does not accept the dictionary.

I get the error:

```
Error: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = release database failed: ConfigMap in version "v1" cannot be handled as a ConfigMap: v1.ConfigMap.Data: ReadMapCB: expect { or n, but found ", error found in #10 byte of ...|","data":"init.sql: |..., bigger context ...|{"apiVersion":"v1","data":"init.sql: |CREATE DATABASE test;\n","kind":"Config|...
```

I am using 
Terraform v0.12.5
+ provider.helm v0.10.0
+ provider.kubernetes v1.8.1

Comment: Why is there a `|` character in there? In YAML that's used for multi-line string literals, but you would need more complex formatting for that to work usually.

Comment: `init.sql` is a file, so the `${file()}` construct results typically in a multi-line string. The example I posted is reduced for simplicity.

Comment: Given that you are having formatting issues that are almost certainly at least related to white space and other specifics, I would edit your question to be more accurate.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The most specific part of the error message I found so far is: `expect { or n`. Since there is little documentation about the formatting, I tried different variations of formatting, without success. Hence, I am looking for someone who was maybe successful in injecting a file as `initdbScript` in terraform. Does that help?

Comment: You can see the full error at the end of it, and as I said the pipe char is formatted wrong. You need a new line and indent after it. And to indent every line after too.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: @MorizMartiner see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the helm plugin's `set` block just like the CLI arguments. The problem is probably how you're referring the `init.sql` inside the `value` field. Instead, put it in the `name` field and escape the `.` with `\\`.

I was able to make it work using this format

```
  set {
    name = "primary.initdb.scripts.init\\.sql"
    value = <<EOF
CREATE USER app_user WITH PASSWORD 'app_password';
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE postgres TO app_user WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT CREATE ON DATABASE postgres TO app_user WITH GRANT OPTION;
ALTER ROLE app_user WITH CREATEROLE;
EOF
  }
```

I haven't tested with an external file but it should work probably be doable using something like this.

```
  set {
    name = "primary.initdb.scripts.init\\.sql"
    value = "${chomp(file("${path.module}/../backend/init.sql"))}"
  }
```

Reference: [Advanced Usage of the “Set” Argument](https://itnext.io/helm-chart-install-advanced-usage-of-the-set-argument-3e214b69c87a)